# element li not allowed as child of element body in this context

Tags: html, html-lists

I'm trying some basic html stuff and I get to this error and I have no idea why is that. Thanks for help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>ČGK Tour 2015 - 2. turnaj - Kotlina</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li>Datum a místo konání: středa 22.4.2015</li>
                </ul>   
    </body>
</html>
```

And I keep getting this error:

> Element "li" not allowed as child of element "body" in this context.
>   (Suppression furter errors from subtree.) From line 16, column 21; to
>   line 16, column 24 (Rule category: Elements structure)

Comment: I've tried your code in JSFiddle, and it is absolutely OK.

Comment: I'am using NetBeans here is the error: http://gyazo.com/203ada23185c9494bc4a4cb6c9258119